# DI how to set connectionstring/dbname to dbcontext after user login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

As my application is multitenant with same codebase and different databases so i need to implement logic to set dbcontext after user login.
I am planning to use DI (mostly Automapper but not final) so If i want to create connectionstring once user logic then is it possible to pass connectionstring to dbcontext through DI or any other approach to set connectionstring per request to dbcontext

Thanks for support

Comment: Automapper  is not a DI solution, its a mapping solution to map between types with similar structures. Maybe you meant AutoFac?

Comment: sorry not automapper but nInject or unity

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implement `Multi tenant` and `multi database` kind of `layered architecture`,I highly recommend to see the implementation of the `ASP.NET Boilerplate`.It is a `free` and `open source`.

> You don't need to reinvent the Wheel

It uses `AutoMapper` as a `mapping library` and `Castle Windsor` as a `DI`.

[**ASP.NET Boilerplate Documentation**](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents)

[**Multi Tenancy**](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy)

**It supports :**

1. Single Deployment - Single Database
2. Single Deployment - Hybrid Databases
3. Multiple Deployment - Single/Multiple/Hybrit Database

It supports **ASP.NET Core** and **Entity Framework Core**.

Here is the latest article about it : [**ASP.NET Core, Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Boilerplate**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115763/Using-ASP-NET-Core-Entity-Framework-Core-and-ASP-N)

Comment: Thanks for reply but my database already exist and it seem boilerplate using their own structure for db. we have separate database for each client mostly same.

Comment: what do you mean by `boilerplate using their own structure for db` ? They don't have such.you can define your `own db structure as you wish`.